# Custom fields in topic form based on forum

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

Lets say I have 2 forums, Forum A and Forum B and two custom fields CF1 and CF2. I want to make the two custom fields available only while creating topic in Forum A, where as for Forum B it should load with default topic form.

Is it possible to do this? Any help or link which help will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are looking for: https://wp-dreams.com/articles/2013/06/adding-custom-fields-bbpress-topic-form/

You should be able to use bbp_get_forum_id() to limit the custom fields to just one or more forums.